# Underscorejs Contains not acting like indexOf

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, contains

I hope someone can explain this to me, in the undescorejs [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#contains), it says:

> Returns true if the value is present in the list. Uses indexOf internally, if list is an Array.

I want to see if the user is on the members page by checking if the path contains `member`. At the moment the path can be '/members/' or '/member/someid`.

So what I have at the moment is

```
_.contains(['/member'],path);
```

Which returns false in both cases, but if I check indexOf

```
path.indexOf('/member');
```

It returns 0 in both cases.

Why does _.contains seem to act differently than indexOf, and how can I fix it?

UPDATE:
I'm planning to test more pages than just `member`, that's why I'm using an array in `contains()`

Comment: If the value is present in the **list**.  `path.indexOf()` is a **string** method, while `.contains()` is for finding values in an array. There's an `indexOf()` on the Array prototype that's *similar* to the string `.indexOf()` but different.

Comment: So `.contains()` does not perform `indexOf()` on each value in the array, but rather on the array as a whole?

Comment: `path.startsWith("/member")`

Comment: If the string doesn't contain the text it will return `-1`, if it returns anything other than `-1` it will give the starting point of that string found. Example: `test/member/` will return `4`. t=0 || e=1 || s=2 || t=3 ||  /member=4

Comment: If you're going to test more than one path, then are you looking to see if at least one matches? If so, use `.some()`... `myArray.some(function(s) { return s.startsWith('/member'); })`

Comment: @Niel right - the array version of `.indexOf()` (which `_.contains()` uses) compares complete values of elements of the array.

Comment: `indexOf` returns a value greater than `-1`, so I'm expecting `contains()` to return true.

Comment: It doesn't return `true` because there is no exact, full match in the array.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, that makes the most sense.

Comment: A simple if statement can be used for `indexOf()` if that is of any use to you.  `if(path.indexOf('/member') > -1){//True}else{//False}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains` searches a list for elements. If the list is `['a','b','c']` and you search for an element `'a'` then you're going to succeed, and if you have a list `['abc','bcd','def']` and you search for an element `'a'` you're going to fail, because that's not in the list. We can trivially write code to demonstrate this:

```
var list = [....];
var find = ...;
list.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log("Is "+find+" the same as ["+element+"]? ", element==find);
});
```

In your example, is `'member'` the same as `'/member'`? It very clearly isn't, they're different strings, and so `contains()` will report the right thing: your string is not contained in the list you're checking.

Comment: Yes I understand now, I was just confused by the docs saying it used `indexOf()`.

Comment: same deal though. `indexOf` (for Arrays, not Strings) checks for elements in a list, so ['abc'].indexOf('a') will be false.